# Rhino Runtime and V8 together?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to have two separate script projects connected to a spreadsheet, one which runs in V8 and one which runs in Rhino?

I have a function that doesn't run in V8 because of a known V8 issue. I was able to make a separate standalone Rhino runtime script and run it from a web app but now I can't find that script anymore as it's not connected to my spreadsheet.  It would be way easier if you could have rhino and V8 in two projects attached to one spreadsheet.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? File>New project

Comment: Hi TheMaster. I thought about that but it's only available from the old IDE as far as I can see. Then I would have to switch between IDEs to find my project later on. Is there a way to create a new project in the new IDE?

Comment: I don't have the new editor yet. Maybe others with new editors will answer. [Edit] your question with relevant information.

Comment: hmm I have used the old IDE and set up a new project. I set it to Rhino Runtime but when I execute the function from a library I get this error:

ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined (line 3, file "Code", project "lib"

If I execute the function locally in the library there is no error. So it seems when I call the Rhino library from a V8 script, it does in fact run under V8. If this is the case it looks like a Web App is indeed the only option to separate V8 and Rhino Runtime.

Comment: @michaeldon What issue do you have with V8 that prevents your function from running?

Comment: @michaeldon When you say "connected to a spreadsheet" do you mean Container-bound scripts? If so, there can only be one. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script

Comment: @Aerials There can be many bound scripts to 1 spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheMaster But which is the one accessed via Tools > Script Editor in the container? I see that using the Apps Script API one can add more scripts and bind them to the same document by assigning a parent. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You can directly create as well: In old IDE> File>New  project. Tools> script editor will then show two project link and will ask you choose 1.

Comment: There is an open issue in Google's Issue tracker about JDBC not running in V8 when called from a library. See here: https://issuetracker.google.com/149273194 . Apart from that a good workaround is using a web app as you mention in the previous comments. Add a star in the issue to let Google know you are affected by it too.